# Same MAC address in LAN

Tags: mac-address

I studied that MAC addresses are physically printed on network card in the computer, and i also know that there can not be two identical mac addresses in the same network LAN. Now my doubt is:

What happens if there are two Devices with the same MAC address in the same LAN? I think this can happen because even if products print different addresses on the cards, there are software tools with which you can change the MAC address. Is someone's connection blocked or what? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong site to ask such a question about networking, but here i've found something you may want to read: https://serverfault.com/questions/462178/duplicate-mac-address-on-the-same-lan-possible

Comment: MAC address is unique, no two devices can't have same MAC address.  But still, network card has intelligence detect the collision as well.